# How to allow '[' and ']' through a Regex check

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, char

I've got the following Regex check, which makes sure that only letters, numbers and `*` characters are input.

```
Regex.IsMatch(searchString, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9*]+$")
```

However, I'd like to extend it to also accept `( ) [ ]` characters too. This is what I've tried so far, but it's returning false:

```
Regex.IsMatch(searchString, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9[]()*]+$")
```

Could anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape them with `\`:

```
Regex.IsMatch(searchString, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]()*]+$")
```

Should be noted that the escaping rules are different depending on whether the character is inside a character class (i.e. `[_chars_]`) or not.

For example - `(` must be escaped to `\(` outside of a character class, because otherwise it denotes the start of a group (i.e. `(_something to capture_)`).  Other characters like `?` and `.` must always be escaped if outside a character class.

*Note*

I've edited out the use of the term 'character *group*' because it's been rightly pointed out to me that, however clearly I try to delineate, it can still cause confusion with a 'group' (capturing/non-capturing).  Regex can be confusing enough as it is without me muddying the waters further.

Comment: `[` doesn't need to be escaped in character classes.

Comment: Not sure I understand - like `[[]`? - I'll take the statement off, though, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You should escape special characters like this:

```
Regex.IsMatch(searchString, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]()*]+$");
```

Comment: you don't need to escape `(` or `)` inside a `[]` group

Comment: @AndrasZoltan There is no escaping on the squared brackets here (and I can't see an edit). Also to confirm `[]` represent character classes, not a group. Groups have a whole different meaning in regex as you obviously know from your answer, but be careful to use the correct terminology.

Comment: @rrrr originally the parentheses were \(\) - which was unnecessary.  I believe 'character group' and 'character class' are interchangeable - a `[]` *group* is a character group.  But perhaps it's best to steer away from using 'group' at all with characters - thus avoiding confusion! :)

Comment: @rrrr have altered my answer to try and be as clear as possible

Comment: @AndrasZoltan Looks good, regex are never the easiest thing to explain!